# Android Studio is library or framework?

Tags: android

Android Developer use Android Studio Software for create android apps . I just wanted to know Android studio Software is a android apps making library or framework  ???

Comment: Android studio is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) . u can simply search `What is Android Studio?`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a tool you use for making android app, i.e It streamlines the process of creating an app by providing you GUI editor, integrated debugger and emulator among other things.